# List specific data from td value searching by data-bind

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, data-binding, return-value

With COVID we started a delivery program from our store. To make tours we get information on a page from a database. But to make the quickest tour we need to copy every single line on a new page and this is alot of work. The list we need to create looks like this:

```
Streetname 1 CITY {ORDERNUMBER}
Streetname 2 CITY {ORDERNUMBER}
Streetname 3 CITY {ORDERNUMBER}
```

We do this by copying every single line. This takes alot of work, while we are able to generate the list by itself. The webpage HTML looks like this:

```
            <table class="table table-framed">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedTourNonDeletedShipments" id="sortable" class="ui-sortable" >
                            <tr>
                                <td id="orderNumber" style="width: 11%"><a data-dismiss="modal" href="ShipmentDetail" data-bind="text: orderNo, click: $root.onShipmentDetail.bind($data)">1151491332</a></td>
                                <td style="width: 9%" data-bind="text: zipcode">1234AB</td>
                                <td style="width: 13%" data-bind="text: city">Arnhem</td>
                                <td style="width: 17%" data-bind="text: deliveryAddress">Streetname 123</td>
                                <td style="width: 12%" data-bind="text: timeSlot">2020-12-27 09:00</td>
                                <td style="width: 8%" data-bind="text: weight">0.77</td>
                                <td style="width: 8%" data-bind="text: volume">0.01</td>
                                <td style="width: 5%"><button id="bRemoveTour" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bind="click: function() { $root.clickRemoveSingleShipment($data) }">X</button></td>
                            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Same things again</td>
            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

What I was thinking is to create this list with the Google Chrome console with Javascript/jQuery. My question is how to get the value from a specific data-bind item in javascript.

Example: How to get the value "Arnhem" where the data-bind = "text: City".

```
<td style="width: 13%" data-bind="text: city">Arnhem</td>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selectors like : `'[data-bind="text: city"]'` or use the index of the cell within the row

Simple example:

```js
$('tbody#sortable tr').each(function(){
   const $cells = $(this).children()
   const order = $cells.eq(0).text(),
         city = $cells.filter('[data-bind="text: city"]').text()
         
  console.log('Order:', order, ' City:',city )      

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-framed">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedTourNonDeletedShipments" id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <tr>
      <td id="orderNumber" style="width: 11%"><a data-dismiss="modal" href="ShipmentDetail" data-bind="text: orderNo, click: $root.onShipmentDetail.bind($data)">1151491332</a></td>
      <td style="width: 9%" data-bind="text: zipcode">1234AB</td>
      <td style="width: 13%" data-bind="text: city">Arnhem</td>
      <td style="width: 17%" data-bind="text: deliveryAddress">Streetname 123</td>
      <td style="width: 12%" data-bind="text: timeSlot">2020-12-27 09:00</td>
      <td style="width: 8%" data-bind="text: weight">0.77</td>
      <td style="width: 8%" data-bind="text: volume">0.01</td>
      <td style="width: 5%"><button id="bRemoveTour" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bind="click: function() { $root.clickRemoveSingleShipment($data) }">X</button></td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I only have problems with getting data from the following line:

      <td id="orderNumber" style="width: 11%"><a data-dismiss="modal" href="ShipmentDetail" data-bind="text: orderNo, click: $root.onShipmentDetail.bind($data)">1151491332</a></td>

Comment: Take a look at the attribute selector docs https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/. Numerous different operators you can use

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm.. I guess that's jQuery and I found out that isn't working in the console. I'll try some things.

Comment: I'm guessing from the `data-bind` that this might be a knockout.js app. Would be much simpler if you could just access the raw data that is being used to bind to (render)  those elements

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got the possibility to edit the RAW files (HTML), it's an external website we are using. I only have the possibility to get the items from the console to get a list. The thing you sent was perfect, brilliant. I was able to tweak it to get the values and output I need. Only the ordernummer is still a problem.

Comment: order number is likely in same position in each row. In my answer it is in cell index `0` and I used `eq(0)` to get that element

Comment: Note you could also look in network tab to see where request is made to get the raw data and make your own request

Comment: I get it now, it's working. Your amazing, thank you very very very much!!